# Which Grails Plug-In can be use to quickly integrate with Twitter

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to use Grails and Twitter Plug-in. Plug-in v0.2 looks like to be pretty old and doesn't work anymore, because it generates incorrect urls.

Which plug-in is current and can be use to quickly integrate with Twitter?

My second question is about Grails - It is mature technology - Is it still growing or is slowly going down?

Comment: I consider grails to be a mature-enough technology and appears to have a growing user base.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Social is an extension of the Spring Framework that allows you to connect your applications with Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) providers such as Facebook and Twitter.

As Grails is based on Spring, try [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social). There is a Grails Spring Social plugin being developed at GitHub: https://github.com/synergyj/grails-spring-social
I am not sure about the plugin maturity, but even if it is not mature/stable, Spring Social as is could be used in a grails app.

As for your second question, my opinion is that grails is mature, and it is being actively developed by SpringSource. Besides that, what do you mean by "growing or going down"?

Comment: Grails-spring-social is not accessible on the Grails Plugins yet. Are there any informations or examples how to use this plugin?

Comment: It looks like it is pretty recent. Why dont you try to contact the plugin developer. He may help with it. Otherwise, you can always use Spring Social directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please split this into two separate questions.

The Twitter4j plugin is the most recent and supports the new OAuth login requirements: http://grails.org/plugin/twitter4j/